# jquery validation server side check

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form post which does some server side validation checks, one of which is a database lookup, if it fails that db check I return the view model back to the form (with a validation error).

What is the best way to tell the jQuery validation to set a rule for the failed field(s) which will return false on the client side (therefore showing the error message/css) until the next submit and check on the server side?

Any ideas welcome

Answer (score -1):

Use one of the following frameworks/classes/snippets/tips:

- http://www.junnark.com/blog/detail/using-jquery-validation-with-aspnet-web-forms
- http://encosia.com/using-jquery-validation-with-asp-net-webforms/
- http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules
- http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/21/combining-jquery-form-validation-and-ajax-submission-with-asp.net.aspx
- http://develoq.net/2011/asp-net-mvc-3-remote-validation-with-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for the links but they all seem to be focused on existing rules such as require, email & min length. I want to returned an "invalid" result for a field (therefore highlighting it as error-ed" until the next form submit and server side validation check?